# What is the default value for tsconfig "include"?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig

In my react native project I'm using [this library](https://wcandillon.gitbook.io/redash/) v1 and in the docs it says to add `"include": ["node_modules/react-native-redash/lib/typescript/v1/index.d.ts"]` to make the types work, and adding that does solve the problem with the library types, but adds another problem.

When I add that `include`, Typescript will only look at the files in the `include` and ignoring all the rest.

I checked the "include" description:

> Specifies a list of glob patterns that match files to be included in compilation. If no 'files' or 'include' property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler defaults to including all files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those specified by 'exclude'. Requires TypeScript version 2.0 or later.

And it says that if I don't add any, the default is all files except the exclude. But by adding an `include`, the default is gone and I lose the default files.

So my question is:

How can I specify the default value of `include` property + `node_modules/react-native-redash/lib/typescript/v1/index.d.ts`? What would be the default value for `include`?

What I have tried so far is doing something like

```
"include": [
  "node_modules/react-native-redash/lib/typescript/v1/index.d.ts",
  "./src"
],
```

But if I add any other path in `include` together with the redash one, all redash errors happen again.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to work with the array you tried.

I know it doesn't answer your question. But perhaps you could try to copy the `index.d.ts` file into your project and referencing it directly, like so:
///

see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

To lint extra files without overriding the defaults...

- Create a file at the root of your directory named `tsconfig.eslint.ts`.
- Add to the file.

  ```json
  {
    "include": [
      "node_modules/react-native-redash/lib/typescript/v1/index.d.ts",
      // other files or directories to include.
    ]
  }
  ```
- Add to your eslint config file.

  ```json
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["./tsconfig.json", "./tsconfig.eslint.json"],
  },
  ```

[Here are the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) on the include glob patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `"**/*"` to include everything from the base url, or `"src/**/*"` to include everything from the src.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), the default tsconfig value for `include` is:

> [] if files is specified; **/* otherwise.